# Pulling reviews from yelp - beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So im trying to grab all the reviews from yelp for the hotel: https://www.yelp.com/biz/capri-laguna-laguna-beach

I have my code below, but I'm unable to pull all the reviews.. I am only able to pull one.. can someone please assist?

I would ideally love to pull all the yelp reviews for this establishment

```html
import time
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

import urllib.request as url


html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.yelp.com/biz/capri-laguna-laguna-beach').read().decode('utf-8')

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

relevant= soup.find_all('p', class_='comment__09f24__gu0rG css-qgunke')

for div in relevant:
        for html_class in div.find_all('span',class_="raw__09f24__T4Ezm"):
            text = html_class.find('span')
            review = html_class.getText(
            
print(review)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting one review printed because you wrote the print statement outside the loop.

```
relevant= soup.find_all('p', class_='comment__09f24__gu0rG css-qgunke')

for div in relevant:
  for html_class in div.find_all('span',class_="raw__09f24__T4Ezm"):
    text = html_class.find('span')
    review = html_class.getText()          
    print(review)
```

If you implement the code above, you'll get all 10 reviews printed.

---

To store all 10 reviews in a list do this,

```
reviews = []

for div in relevant:
  for html_class in div.find_all('span',class_="raw__09f24__T4Ezm"):
    text = html_class.find('span')
    review = html_class.getText()
    reviews.append(review)
```